# Formatting data as table with AWK print

Tags: awk, osx, top

I'm trying to write a code to print the top 10 processes running on macOS.
But when I run this code `top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10 | awk 'NR==12, NR==22 {print $2,$3,$8}';` the output is not organized in a table format with rows and columns. How can I format the output?

P.S. I tried this `top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10 | awk 'BEGIN {printf("%s %10s %8s \n" ,"NAME", "%CPU", "MEM")}
{printf("%s %10f %8s\n",NR==12, NR==22, $2, $3, $8)}';` but it doesn't work either (it doesn't even display the correct data.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide the input for the awk command you want help writing (i.e. the output of `top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10`) and the output of said awk command so we can then help you write it. Without sample input/output we're just guessing at what you want to do in your awk script. I can't imagine what you thought `printf("%s %10f %8s\n",NR==12, NR==22, $2, $3, $8)` would do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I get from `top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10 | awk 'NR==12, NR==22 {print $2,$3,$8}';`:

```
COMMAND %CPU MEM
WindowServer 0.0 574M+
Google Chrome 1
kernel_task 0.0 1183M+
postbox 0.0 1027M+
Google Chrome 1186+
coreaudiod 0.0 6416K+
Google Chrome 1
Telegram 0.0 364M+
Google Chrome 1
Slack Helper 1
```

This *is* a table with rows and column. If you want to format it better you can pipe it into `column`.

`top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10 | awk 'NR==12, NR==22 {print $2,$3,$8}' | column -t`:

```
COMMAND       %CPU    MEM
WindowServer  0.0     549M+
Google        Chrome  1
kernel_task   0.0     1174M+
postbox       0.0     1027M+
Google        Chrome  1185+
coreaudiod    0.0     6416K+
Google        Chrome  1
Telegram      0.0     365M+
Google        Chrome  1
Slack         Helper  1
```

EDIT: Since `top` delimits these fields with whitespace there will be problems with parsing out the correct columns. Setting the column via `-stats` might be better:

`top -l 1 -u -o cpu -n10 -stats command,cpu,mem | awk '/COMMAND/{y=1;next}y'`

```
WindowServer     0.0  560M+
Google Chrome He 0.0  402M+
kernel_task      0.0  1170M+
postbox          0.0  1027M+
Google Chrome    0.0  235M+
coreaudiod       0.0  6408K+
Google Chrome He 0.0  161M+
Telegram         0.0  364M+
Google Chrome He 0.0  107M+
Slack Helper (Re 0.0  307M+
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with the ps command.
Able to get the output in table format.

```
ps axo command,%cpu,%mem|awk 'NR <=11'
COMMAND                     %CPU %MEM
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --  1.0  1.3
[kthreadd]                   0.0  0.0
[ksoftirqd/0]                0.0  0.0
[kworker/0:0]                0.0  0.0
[kworker/0:0H]               0.0  0.0
[kworker/u2:0]               0.0  0.0
[migration/0]                0.0  0.0
[rcu_bh]                     0.0  0.0
[rcu_sched]                  0.2  0.0
[watchdog/0]                 0.0  0.0
```